# Laravel Excel table styles not applied to spreadsheet

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

How to make a spreadsheet with styles coming using the table styles in [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl)?

I already have the view I want:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Tema/Sub Tema/Sub-sub Tema:</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kelompok/Usia:</td>
            <td>{{ $group->name }} / {{ $group->age_range }} tahun</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">No</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Nama Anak</td>
            @foreach ($fod_indicators as $fod_indicator)
            <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            @endforeach
            <td colspan="4">ID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach ($fod_indicators as $fod_indicator)
            <td colspan="4">
                <b>{{ $fod_indicator->fod->name }}</b> <br />
                {{ $fod_indicator->indicator->name }}
            </td>
            @endforeach
            <td>CP / STTPA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach ($fod_indicators as $fod_indicator)
            <td colspan="4">{{ $fod_indicator->indicator->assessment_technique }}</td>
            @endforeach
            <td>Teknik Penilaian</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach ($fod_indicators as $fod_indicator)
            <td>BB</td>
            <td>MB</td>
            <td>BSH</td>
            <td>BSB</td>
            @endforeach
            <td>Keterangan</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($scores as $score)
        <tr>
            <td align="center">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $score->child->full_name }}</td>
            @foreach ((object) json_decode($score->scores) as $indicator_star)
                @for ($star = 1; $star <= 4; $star ++)
                <td width="40" align="center">{!! $indicator_star->stars == $star ? '&#10004;' : '&nbsp;' !!}</td>
                @endfor
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Catatan Anekdot:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $report->notes }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

This is what Its looks like on browser

[image]

But this is what I get on the excel

[image]

I already looked into the website, but there are no documentation for the table view, I wanted to using https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/extending.html#customize, but it says

> You are able to hook into the parent package by using events. No need
>   to use convenience methods like "query" or "view", if you need full
>   control over the export.

Is there anyway to do it from the table style directly? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @Khrisna. Did you manage to find a solution, tutorial, or anything like it to help with the table style? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @George, I did find the solution, but you need to create a macro for it. Here's the [link](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/extending.html#macroable). After that, you need to add some macros that you need from here [link](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Hi, @George I just add my answer here, please check. Hope you can understand what I'm trying to explain. (English is not my main language)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I should share my solutions long ago here, but I'm sorry if my explanations are not good enough, hope you will understand what I'm trying to explain in here.

First, you need to create a new provider called `PHPExcelMacroServiceProvider` in `App\Providers\` which you will put all the macros that you needed for making the excel files, and this is what it looks like in my provider file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
Use \Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet;
use \Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer;

class PHPExcelMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Page format macros
         */
        Writer::macro('setCreator', function (Writer $writer, string $creator) {
            $writer->getDelegate()->getProperties()->setCreator($creator);
        });

        Sheet::macro('setOrientation', function (Sheet $sheet, $orientation) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation($orientation);
        });

        /**
         * Cell macros
         */
        Writer::macro('setCellValue', function (Writer $writer, string $cell, string $data) {
            $writer->getDelegate()->setCellValue($cell, $data);
        });

        Sheet::macro('styleCells', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, array $style) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->applyFromArray($style);
        });

        Sheet::macro('horizontalAlign', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, string $align) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal($align);
        });

        Sheet::macro('verticalAlign', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, string $align) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getAlignment()->setVertical($align);
        });

        Sheet::macro('wrapText', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        });

        Sheet::macro('mergeCells', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->mergeCells($cellRange);
        });

        Sheet::macro('columnWidth', function (Sheet $sheet, string $column, float $width) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getColumnDimension($column)->setWidth($width);
        });

        Sheet::macro('rowHeight', function (Sheet $sheet, string $row, float $height) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getRowDimension($row)->setRowHeight($height);
        });

        Sheet::macro('setFontFamily', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, string $font) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setName($font);
        });

        Sheet::macro('setFontSize', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, float $size) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize($size);
        });

        Sheet::macro('textRotation', function (Sheet $sheet, string $cellRange, int $degrees) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getAlignment()->setTextRotation($degrees);
        });

    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You can find the properties you want from [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you just need to search what function or format you want, and then add it to the provider file with following this rule https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/extending.html#sheet.

after that, make sure to add `PHPExcelMacroServiceProvider` to `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    ... // Bunch of providers

    App\Providers\PHPExcelMacroServiceProvider::class, // Add this provider to the list

],
```

So to use the macro you just make in the `app/Exports/ExampleReportExport.php`, I just need to call the macro. Ex:

```
$event->sheet->wrapText('A1:AC100');
$event->sheet->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$event->sheet->setFontFamily('A1:AC100', 'Times New Roman');
$event->sheet->horizontalAlign('D1:Q2' , \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$event->sheet->horizontalAlign('E6:X6' , \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$event->sheet->verticalAlign('A1:AC100' , \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
$event->sheet->verticalAlign('A8:D100' , \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
$event->sheet->horizontalAlign('A6:X7', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
$event->sheet->horizontalAlign('E8:AC100', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER); 
$event->sheet->verticalAlign('E7:X7' , \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_BOTTOM);
$event->sheet->verticalAlign('A8:D100' , \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
$event->sheet->horizontalAlign('A8:D100', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT); 
$event->sheet->textRotation('E7:X7', 90);
```

I'll be glad if there's someone that understand what I'm trying to explain and willing to edit my explanation so my answer is more readable and more understandable for the others. :)

Comment: Thank you! Just one important thing is that the macros actually encapsulate the works of Phpspreadsheet, which is actually what's used to apply the style to the sheet, if I understood correctly. It all derives from `getDelegate()->getStyle` or something like that. My problem was exactly from where those methods were coming, the macros, and this helped.

Comment: @George actually `$sheet->getDelegate()` is the same with `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()`, you can read about it on https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/extending.html#macroable. I had a headache from this problem, but finally, when I read about it, I tried to makes my own macro, and it's working :D. Glad my solution is helping you as well. Cheers!

Comment: @George I just realized that you edited my question, thank you! hope you can do the same with my answer, so it's more understandable :D

Comment: Can ou explain with more detais, how to use the macros in exportclass. Can ou copy this class?

Comment: Hi @CristianBudzicz, you can use the macro by importing the `\Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet` class

Answer (score 0):

```
            $styleArray = [
                'font' => [
                    'bold' => true,
                ],
                'alignment' => [
                    'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT,
                ],
                'borders' => [
                    'allBorders' => [
                        'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
                    ],

                ],
                'fill' => [
                    'fillType' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                    'rotation' => 90,
                    'startColor' => [
                        'argb' => 'FFA0A0A0',
                    ],
                    'endColor' => [
                        'argb' => 'FFFFFFFF',
                    ],
                ],
            ];

            $to = $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getHighestColumn();
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle('A1:'.$to.'1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```